# Vue: changing value of a data property used in v-model doesn't render the newly set value

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm currently in the process of creating a stepper component using Vue with Vuex. Each step is a component that holds a input fields. Each step stores the values of the input fields in the Vuex store. When going to a previous step, the already available data should be loaded from the store and displayed in the respective input field.

I'm using a custom input component that implements the v-model directive correctly.

```html
<custom-input v-model="amount"
              v-bind:type="'number'"></custom-input>
```

"amount" is defined in the data function:

```
data: function () {
  return {
    amount: null
  }
}
```

Now I'm trying to set the value of the v-model property when the component gets mounted.

```
mounted() {
  this.amount = this.$store.state.fields.amount.value;
}
```

Through debugging tools I can see that the store holds the correct value. The same is the case for the amount data-property of the component.

I've also tried setting the property using the set method like this:

```
this.$set(this.$data, 'amount', this.$store.state.fields.amount.value);
```

But it still does not show up in the custom-input.

How do I set the data property used in v-model correctly so that it shows up in the input field?

**EDIT**

The custom-input component is implemented like this:

```html
<input type="'text'" v-on:input="onInput">
```

```
onInput: function (event) {
  this.$emit('input', event.target.value);
}
```

Comment: You should look at this https://scotch.io/tutorials/add-v-model-support-to-custom-vuejs-component

Comment: Since the question is about `custom-input`, it would help to see the source of `custom-input`. It might be a problem with the way you've implemented `v-model`.

Comment: Thanks for the remark, I've added the source now. I've implemented it according to this [guide](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components). @tony19

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I did not actually bind the value property within the custom-input component. Adding this fixed the problem:

```html
<custom-input ... :value="value" />
```